# Is there a way to send multiple messages at once using Instabot?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, instagram

I'm working on a survey that I want to send to multiple Instagram users from my school. To do so, I used instabot and python to send them the message. I am currently able to send a message to one user each time I run the program. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="myUsername", password="myPassword")

list = ["randomUsername1", "randomUsername2", "randomUsername3"]

for x in list:
    bot.send_message("This is a test", [x])
```

How do I use a loop instead of manually sending a message to each user?

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_message("This is a test", ["user1", "user2", "user3"])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).